# Vector containing templates throws error on pushback

Tags: c++, vector, return

Intro:
I have 3 objects:

```
class cars;
template<class T> class types : public cars;
template<class T> exposition{
vector<T*> car_vector;
...};
```

It is a school project, and I must use upcasts and downcasts a lot. I've managed to add the 5 types of cars into the vector like this:

```
void add(T* toadd) {
    int opt;
    cout << "\n\t 1) Add cabrio";
    cout << "\n\t\t Your option: "; cin >> opt;
    switch (opt) {
        case 1: {
            toadd = new types<cabrio>(name, price);
            types<cabrio> *a = dynamic_cast<types<cabrio>*>(toadd);
            car_vector.push_back(a);
            incr();
            break;
        }
```

I've cut some of the useless code for the demonstration. It works, if I use the following code to print the vector, the types are ok ( typeids are templates and all):

```
void toString() {
    for (auto i : v_masini)
    {
        cout << "\n\t "<< i->get_type(); // returns typeid(*i).name()
            cout << "\t "; i->toString();
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Now, I had to make another class for sells and purchases. It must contain a vector of 'supersport' cars. The following implementation throws an error saying that it cannot convert from cars to const types&, although if I print the typeid of (*i) it says it is a type...

```
vector<types<supersport>> get_ss() {
    vector<types<supersport>> to_return;
    for (auto i : car_vector)
        if (i->get_type() == "class supersport")
        {
            to_return.push_back(*i);
        };
    return to_return;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast` will return a `nullptr` if the upcast is not valid

Comment: Also note that `typeid(T).name()` returns an implementation-defined value, and it's safer to do something like `(i->get_type() == typeid(your_supersport_type))`, where `get_type()` could return just the `typeid`, not its name

Comment: I think it was valid since I've printed the vector in the format " type, name, price " and it matched my input.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I've tested that in my debugging for loop and they don't match. But I don't understant where the problem is.

Comment: Update: the class names actually match, somehow... the class name is "class types<class supersport> ", and in vector they show up the same, but ( typeid(*i).name() == typeid(types<supersport>) returns false... I understand nothing

Comment: As an alternative to alter igel 's suggestion, my pitch is you add pure virtual functions to the base class that are implemented by derived classes to do things specific to that derived class. That way you never have to know what the derived class is.